# How can the sum of sequences be obtained in the given form?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Find this sequence:

```
a[n_] := n p (1 - p)^(n - 1)
Sum[a[k], {k, 1, 9}]
```

get the result is：

```
p + 2 (1 - p) p + 3 (1 - p)^2 p + 4 (1 - p)^3 p + 5 (1 - p)^4 p + 
 6 (1 - p)^5 p + 7 (1 - p)^6 p + 8 (1 - p)^7 p + 9 (1 - p)^8 p
```

How can the sum of sequences be obtained in this form?

```
(1 - (1 - p)^9)/p - 9 (1 - p)^9
```

Comment: If you already know the function, then generate the n-th term. `(Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n}] // Distribute // First@# + Factor@Rest@# &) /. 
 n -> 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us treat `S[n]` as the solution of the recurrence equation

```
RSolve[{S[n] - S[n - 1] == n*p*(1 - p)^(n - 1), S[1] == p}, S[n], n]
```

> `{{S[n] -> -((-1 + (1 - p)^n + n (1 - p)^n p)/p)}}`

```
(S[n] /. %) /. n -> 9
```

> `{-((-1 + (1 - p)^9 + 9 (1 - p)^9 p)/p)}`